# Orange WAMP Icon - I don't have skype

Tags: icons, wamp

I'm using wamp 2.2 on a Windows 7 machine without Skype, Esset or any of the programs that may conflict with the connections. Yet the icon stays orange - I have also tried to change the port that WAMP uses but unfortunately, this hasn't worked either. My hosts file is completely empty with only the following inside:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 www.mysite.dev mysite.dev

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you try running apache through the command line you may get some more useful errors. Have you checked the Apache error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wamp manager icon is Orange then EITHER the Apache or MySQL service has not started, first check which one has not started.

How to tell which service is not running if the wampmanager icon is orange.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then Apache is running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> MySQL -> Service
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then MySQL is running.

So is it Apache or MySQL that has failed to start

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be sass.  Apache couldn't boot because sass had created some files that apache mistook and couldn't read.  I remove the sass director from my www/ and it booted without a problem.